# Is a refurbished Macbook Pro's battery new?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

When you buy a refurbished Macbook direct from Apple, is the battery in it new? I cannot seem to find a definitive answer on their website or on the internet. I am concerned that the savings from buying a refurb will be cancelled out by having to replace the battery in less than a year.

Comment: Once you have one you can check the number of charge cycles.

Comment: I understand I can check after buying. I was hoping to find out prior to buying a refurbished model.

Comment: you can buy one and if you are not happy you have 14 days to return it. If you are really not happy about buying a macbook with a battery with a few chanrges done, then there will be many other things that will stop you buying referb.

Comment: a few is no problem; 1/2 of the battery's available cycles is a problem.

Comment: If you mean literally "in less than a year", you'd be covered by the warranty - refurbs carry the same warranty as new machines and qualify for AppleCare in exactly the same way (i.e., you can buy AC anytime before your 1-year warranty expires).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I called Apple's Sale Support, and I asked them what their policy was for batteries in a refurbished Macbook. Their answer is that the battery will be replaced if it has a defect, but if nothing is wrong with it, then the laptop will include the original battery which may or may not have many used cycles.

Answer (score 1):

This is not answering your question, merely providing a data point, but my refurbished MacBook Air (purchased very late December 2011) currently has a single cycle on its battery. I didn't check the machine when it came out the box, but I'd imagine it was probably at zero cycles when I received it (as I've probably put that cycle on it myself in the month I've had it).

Comment: As a second data point, I ended up buying a refurbished MacBook Pro, and it had 3 cycles out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

mine had 3 cycles when i received it. currently at 7% life left and have not yet charged it since I got it.

Answer (score 0):

I just received a refurbished 2015 MacBook Pro today (April 20, 2017) and the power cycles shows 0.  The product also looks brand new.

I have bought several refurbished iPads before, and the same thing.

I would guess the only way Apple leaves the original battery in there is if it had a relatively low power cycle count.  Apple wants you to buy the refurbished products from them.  And I stand by it.  Every refurbished product I have bought through them looks brand new.  Well worth it!

Answer (score 0):

I was told by an Apple employee (not a store employee) that most refurb computers are just returns and open boxes, and not computers that were actually used by anyway.